# Find string similarities between two dimensions in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, string-comparison, data-analysis

I have two tables and I want to find matches where values can be found in one of the tables and where they are in the second.

In table A I have a list over search queries by users, and in table B I have a list over a selection of search queries I want to find. To make this work I want to use a method similar to:

```
SELECT UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY('shackleford', 'shackelford') FROM DUAL
```

I have used this method, but it does not work as it can be a difference between the query and the name in selection.

```
SELECT query FROM search_log WHERE query IN (SELECT navn FROM selection_table);
```

Are there any best practice methods for finding similarities through a query?

Comment: Without an exemple of data in your two tables it is hard to understand what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach might be something like:

```
SELECT 
    SEARCH_LOG.QUERY
FROM 
    SEARCH_LOG
WHERE 
    EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 
            NULL 
        FROM 
            SELECTION_TABLE
        WHERE
            UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY(SEARCH_LOG.QUERY, SELECTION_TABLE.NAVN) >= 98
    );
```

This will return rows in `SEARCH_LOG` that have a row in `SELECTION_TABLE` where `NAVN` matches `QUERY` with a score of at least 98 (out of 100).  You could change the 98 to whatever threshold you prefer.

This is a "brute force" approach because it potentially looks at all combinations of rows.  So, it might not be "best practice", but it might still be practical.  If performance is important, you might consider a more sophisticated solution like Oracle Text.

Comment: You should use `EXIST` since `IN` is strictly for equality: `EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM selection_table WHERE <your_condition>)`

Comment: Of course! Thanks @VincentMalgrat for pointing that out.  I've edited the answer accordingly.